# Tensorflow can't find libcuda.so (CUDA 7.5)

Tags: python, cuda, tensorflow

I've installed CUDA 7.5 toolkit, and Tensorflow inside anaconda env. The CUDA driver is also installed. The folder containing the `so` libraries is in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. When I import tensorflow I get the following error:

> Couldn't open CUDA library libcuda.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64

In this folder, there exist a file named `libcudart.so`  (which is actually a symbolic link to `libcudart.so.7.5`). So (just as a guess) I created a symbolic link to `libcudart.so` named `libcuda.so`. Now the library is found by Tensorflow, but as soon as I call `tensorflow.Session()` I get the following error:

> F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:107] Check failed: f
>   != nullptr could not find cuInitin libcuda DSO; dlerror:
>   /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5: undefined symbol: cuInit

Any ideas?

Comment: libcuda is part of the CUDA driver, not the CUDA toolkit. Have you installed the CUDA driver?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning it. The examples which come with CUDA compile and run without errors.

Comment: `libcuda.so` and `libcudart.so` are not the same thing.  And while `libcudart.so` should probably be in `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64` on your machine, `libcuda.so` should be somewhere else.  And the symbolic link from `libcuda.so` to `libcudart.so` is a completely broken idea.  They are **different libraries**.

Comment: Ok, I suspected that, that's why I wrote it was just a guess. So, why is the libcuda.so missing? Maybe the installation is broken?

Comment: You should attempt to discover where `libcuda.so` is on your machine.  There are linux utilities which can find files for you, such as `find`.  Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Ok thanks. I found it and added the containing folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it loads ok. I get a different error, but it is unrelated to this question.

Comment: The `libcuda.so` should be in some location like `/usr/lib64` on your machine (it may vary by linux distro).  That is the one you want to use and the folder you want to include in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  There is probably a `libcuda.so` in `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/stubs` directory on your machine.  You *don't* want to be using that.  It exists for a different purpose.

Comment: It is indeed found under `stubs` as you mention, and under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` which is (?) a 32-version - is it?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to decode directory naming conventions on your linux distro when you haven't indicated what your linux distro is.  In any event, the `stubs` version is *not* the correct version to use, and you should never put the `stubs` path in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.   As @talonmies indicated, the driver is the entity that installs the `libcuda.so` file, and it will not install it anywhere in the `/usr/local/cuda...` path, it will install it "somewhere else", which varies by linux distro.

Comment: Thanks. My distro is Ubuntu 14.04. Anyway, eventually it was a problem with NVIDIA driver which was already installed with older/wrong version. I removed it completely and re-installed the latest driver, and everything works now. The library is now found under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Thanks for all the helpful comments.

Comment: @ItamarKatz: Please add a short answer summarising what you did to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here is what I found out and what I did to solve this problem.
The system is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. The NVIDIA driver version that I was trying to install was 367.35. The installation resulted in an error towards the end, with message:

> ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia-drm'

However the CUDA samples compiled and run with no problem, so the driver was at least partially installed correctly. However, when I checked the version using:

> cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version

The version I got was different (I don't remember exactly but some 352 sub-version). 
So I figured out I better remove all traces of the driver and re-install. I followed the instructions in the accepted answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely, except for the command that makes sure nouveau driver will be loaded in boot.

I finally reinstalled the most up-to-date NVIDIA driver (367.35). The installation finished with no errors and Tensorflow was able to load all libraries.

I think the problem began when someone who worked on the installation before me used `apt-get` to install the driver, and not a `run` script. Not sure however.

**PS** during installation there *is* a warning:

> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure
>   you want to continue?

Looking at the logs I could locate this pre-install script, and its content is simply:

```
# Trigger an error exit status to prevent the installer from overwriting
# Ubuntu's nvidia packages.
exit 1
```

so it seems ok to install despite this warning.

Comment: Thank you for adding the answer. I am hoping that adding a few good, canonical "I can't make tensorflow build/work/run" will help reduce the volume of redundant and borderline off-topic questions which the release of tensorflow has triggered.

Comment: I know my question was borderline off-topic, but I reviewed answers on other websites and I didn't have much hope getting help there. I decided to pay the inevitable downvotes on SO and get help - which I did.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on a couple of Ubuntu 16.04 machines. I tried just updating the NVIDIA drivers and Cuda toolkit hoping that `apt` would take care of replacing the missing file, but that didn't happen.

Here's a hopefully clear explanation of how I fixed an error like:

```
...libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You are missing this `libcuda.so.1` file apparently.
If you look at other SO posts, you will discover that `libcuda.so.1` is actually a symbolic link (fancy Unix term for a thing that looks like a file but actually is just a pointer to another file). Specifically, it is a symbolic link to a libcuda.so.# file *that is part of the NVIDIA graphics drivers!!!* (not part of the Cuda toolkit). So if you do find wherever the package manager has put the `libcuda.so.1` file on your system, you'll see it's pointing to this driver-related file:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 -la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Oct 25 14:29 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.410.73
```

Okay, so you need to make a symbolic link like the one you found, but where?
I.e., where is Tensorflow looking for this `libcuda.so.1`? Obviously not where your package manager stuck it.
It turns out that Tensorflow looks in the "load library path".
You can see this path like so:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and what you get back should include the installed Cuda toolkit:

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

(The exact path might vary on your system)
If not, you need to add the toolkit to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH using some shell command like this (from the NVIDIA Toolkit install manual):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

(If you don't find anything in `/usr/local/cuda` you might not have the toolkit installed.)

**Now** that you know where Tensorflow looks on the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Cuda toolkit, you can add a *symbolic link* to the toolkit directory.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.410.73  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcuda.so.1
```

Or you can just listen to other posts that don't explain what's going on but instead tell you to try installing more things in a bunch of different ways. Didn't work for me though :(