# Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0' in ubuntu 18.04 with anaconda virtual environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, anaconda

I'm facing troubles when trying to run object detection python scripts with tensorflow-gpu 1.14
I have a pre-built machine with virtual environments.
When I run scripts the following error happens. I say error because I want to use GPU, probably if I don't stop the script it will run correctly, but on CPU.

```
2020-03-24 14:06:12.475574: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-24 14:06:12.475698: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-24 14:06:12.475816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-24 14:06:12.475927: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-24 14:06:12.476035: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-24 14:06:12.476144: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-03-24 14:06:12.480006: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
```

Now, since I'm using a prepared environments, I think that configuration is ok, however I made lots of checks and I can't find out if there's a problem with it.

Here some checks I performed

```
cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
sudo make
./deviceQuery
```

Here the response

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Tesla M60"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          10.2 / 10.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.2
  Total amount of global memory:                 7619 MBytes (7988903936 bytes)
  (16) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     2048 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1178 MHz (1.18 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2505 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Enabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device supports Compute Preemption:            No
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 0 / 30
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.2, CUDA Runtime Version = 10.0, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

I think that the problem could be related to the fact I'm using a virtual environment. I'm new to virtual env, so I don't know how installations path and environment variables are  managed in this cases.

I followed NickleDave comment at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421840/tensorflow-cant-find-libcuda-so-cuda-7-5) to understand the behavior, so I'm guessing these paths could not be the same, in my case, because I have an environment built with anaconda.

Anyone has a suggestion on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks in advance